# Watching 2 videos at the same time by splitting into audio channels

Tags: windows-7, windows, video, youtube

I'm trying to watch 2 Youtube videos at once on Windows 7 using a headphone by directing the audio from the 2 videos into 2 different ears. I.e. the audio from one video only uses the left channel, the audio from the other video only uses the other channel. This way, I can watch 2 videos at the same time.
Is there a software that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use two windows of [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/index.html), go to Open Network Stream (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>) then go to Audio - Audio Channels - Left/Right

Comment: This does not work for me. The audio is the same no matter which option I select. And I know for sure my speaker does support stereo audio.

Comment: try two player at the same time, VLC and MPC 1 playing in mono mode + left another play in Mono Mode+Right